# How to join another table in $lookup mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How to join another table in $lookup mongoose.I want to join three collections in MongoDB using the aggregate $lookup. Is it possible to join?. The json data in the collection is shown below:-

```
     data:
     {    
      "_id" : ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd"),
      "email" : "admin@gmail.com",
      "otherinfo": ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906003"),
      "deleted": false,
    }

userinfo:

    {
     "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906003"),
     "userId" : "AD",
     "userRoleID: ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf90ef3"),
     "phone" : "0000000000"
    }
userrole:

   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906ef3"),
    "username" : "AD",
    "role" : "admin"
   }
```

The mongoose query is like this:-

```
await data.aggregate([
  { "$match": {deleted: false} },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "userinfo",
      localField: "otherinfo",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "extradetails"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "userrole",
      localField: "userinfo.userRoleID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userRole"
    }
  },
])
```

Please help me in correcting the query.

Comment: Your `data.deleted` field is a string; while you are querying it with a boolean value

Comment: The result from the userinfo lookup will be stored in an array in the "extradetails" field, so there will never be a "userinfo.userRoleId" field.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `userinfo.userRoleID` field value is not equal `userrole._id` field value. It may be a typo.

As @Joe's comment says, the output array field is called `extradetails`(specified by `as`) in the first `$lookup` pipeline stage, and the documents pass through the aggregation pipeline stages in sequence. Each pipeline stage will output the documents.

So, after the first `$lookup` pipeline stage, the output documents are:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd",
    "deleted": false,
    "email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "extradetails": [
      {
        "_id": "56d82612b63f1c31cf906003",
        "phone": "0000000000",
        "userId": "AD",
        "userRoleID": "56d82612b63f1c31cf906ef3"
      }
    ],
    "otherinfo": "56d82612b63f1c31cf906003"
  }
]
```

These documents will be used as input documents for the next pipeline stage.

The `localField` should be `"extradetails.userRoleID"`, not `"userinfo.userRoleID"`.

The aggregation pipeline stages:

```js
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      deleted: false
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "userinfo",
      "localField": "otherinfo",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "extradetails"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "userrole",
      localField: "extradetails.userRoleID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userRole"
    }
  },
  
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rCHbIs4pxar)